# Using choose in frequency Haskell QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

So I have the code below and I am trying to make it an instance of `Arbitrary`:

```
data MyData = I Int | B Bool

instance Arbitrary MyData where
  arbitrary = do {
     frequency [(1, return (I 1)),
                (1, return (choose((B True), (B False))))]
  }
```

With this however I get (understandable) the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Gen MyData’ with ‘MyData’
      Expected type: Gen MyData
        Actual type: Gen (Gen MyData)
```

How can I accomplish to implement this? Also instead of (`I 1`) I would like to return `I` with a random `Int`. However using the `arbitrary` function instead of `1` leads to the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to want to distribute evenly between `I` and `B` constructors, a simpler solution would be to use [oneof](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:oneof) instead of `frequency`:

```
data MyData = I Int | B Bool deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary MyData where
  arbitrary = oneof [genI, genB]
    where genI = fmap I arbitrary 
          genB = fmap B arbitrary
```

The `genI` and `genB` generators use the underlying `Arbitrary` instances of `Int` and `Bool` by mapping raw integers and Boolean values to the respective case constructors.

Here's a set of sample data:

```
> sample (arbitrary :: Gen MyData)
B False
B False
I 2
B False
I 1
I 7
B False
B False
B True
I 7
B False
```

As you can see, it also accomplishes to pick arbitrary integers.

---

The code in the OP has several problems. The first error message is that the return type is nested. One way to get around that is to remove the `do` notation. This, however, doesn't solve the problem.

Even if you reduce it to the following, it doesn't type-check:

```
instance Arbitrary MyData where
  arbitrary =
     frequency [(1, return (I 1)),
                (1, choose(B True, B False))]
```

This attempt produces the error:

```
Q72160684.hs:10:21: error:
    * No instance for (random-1.1:System.Random.Random MyData)
        arising from a use of `choose'
    * In the expression: choose (B True, B False)
      In the expression: (1, choose (B True, B False))
      In the first argument of `frequency', namely
        `[(1, return (I 1)), (1, choose (B True, B False))]'
   |
10 |                 (1, choose(B True, B False))]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `choose` method requires the input to be `Random` instances, which `MyData` isn't.

---

If you really want to use `frequency` rather than `oneof`, the easiest way may be to first get `oneof` to work, since you can view `frequency` as a generalisation of `oneof`.

First, to make the code a little more succinct, I've used `<$>` instead of `fmap` and then inlined both generators:

```
instance Arbitrary MyData where
  arbitrary = oneof [I <$> arbitrary, B <$> arbitrary]
```

Now replace `oneof` with `frequency` and change each generator to a weighted tuple:

```
instance Arbitrary MyData where
  arbitrary = frequency [(10, I <$> arbitrary), (1, B <$> arbitrary)]
```

Sampling from this instance illustrates that the distribution is now skewed:

```
> sample (arbitrary :: Gen MyData)
I 0
I (-2)
I (-4)
I (-1)
I 0
I 8
B True
I 1
I 3
I (-3)
I (-16)
```

There are 10 `I` values and only 1 `B` value.

Answer (score 5):

You can derive it with [*generic-random*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random-1.5.0.1/docs/Generic-Random-DerivingVia.html) ([since *1.5.0.0*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random/changelog)).

Deriving via `GenericArbitraryU`: Gives a uniform distribution (like `oneof` from Mark Seemann's answer):

```
{-# Language DataKinds     #-}
{-# Language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# Language DerivingVia   #-}

import Test.QuickCheck
import GHC.Generics

import Generic.Random.DerivingVia

-- ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
-- ghci> sample @MyData arbitrary
-- I 0
-- I 1
-- B True
-- I 6
-- I (-5)
-- I (-7)
-- B True
-- I (-10)
-- B True
-- B True
-- I (-9)
data MyData = I Int | B Bool
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic)

  deriving Arbitrary
  via GenericArbitraryU MyData
```

Deriving via `GenericArbitrary`: gives a weighted distribution specified by a type-level list of numbers. They denote the frequency of each constructor (like `frequency`):

```
-- ghci> sample @MyData arbitrary
-- I 0
-- I (-2)
-- I 4
-- I 5
-- I 2
-- I 0
-- B False
-- I (-9)
-- I (-10)
-- I (-3)
-- I (-8)
data MyData = I Int | B Bool
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic)

  deriving Arbitrary
  via GenericArbitrary '[10, 1] MyData
```